# What is GeckoView's relation with exoplayer2?

Tags: android, kotlin, firefox, webview, geckoview

When looking at mozilla's maven GeckoView directory you will see a bunch of build types nightly beta, specific builds for architecture, etc.

You can see these 3 directories in it.

- geckoview-exoplayer2-beta/
- geckoview-exoplayer2-nightly/
- geckoview-exoplayer2/

Is this a seperate GeckoView version with ExoPlayer integrated? Is this a customized exoplayer2 that's integrated in GeckoView? What's the purpose?
I can't find any information about this.

[https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Searched through the geckoview docs but theres not even a reference to it.

Comment: Searching bring up this bug thread: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1523544 which makes reference to HLS or HTTP Live Streaming. By implication GeckoView may be using Exoplayer2 for handling that use case.